# How can I implement an interface method that accepts any parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a EnemyManager that handles class instances that implement an interface: IEnemy.

```
public class EnemyManager
{
   public void AddEnemy(IEnemy enemy)
   {
      // Initialize enemy ...
   }
}

public interface IEnemy
{
   void Init<T>(T enemyData);
}
```

I want every instance to be initialized with a different custom type: EvilSkeletonData, BossEnemyData ... etc. But I do not want to create an overload for each of those datatypes to maintain my interface as clean as possible.

I was thinking that Generics could work but perhaps it defeats the purpose as I would need to explicitly convert the data on each IEnemy implementation:

```
public class EvilSkeleton : IEnemy
{
   public void Init<T>(T enemyData)
   {
      var enemyData = initParams as EvilSkeletonData;
      if(enemyData != null)
      {
          // Logic here
      } 
   }
}
```

What would be a clean (and if possible efficient) way to solve this?

Comment: Same as any other polymorphic representation; you treat an IEnemy as an IEnemy and not as a specific enemy. What is common about an enemy?

Comment: Maybe you need `IEnemy<T>`.

Comment: Why just don't make `IEnemy` generic itself?

Comment: You don't want a class per "enemy type". Take a more generic approach, without generics.  What are the differences between the enemy types? Then store that in properties that all instances share, such as Damage and Health. If you're showing a simplification of your actual problem, that still applies. And otherwise, they have no use implementing a shared interface if they don't share behavior.

Comment: I cannot treat each IEnemy exactly the same because they depend on external data clases that I cannot modify. So perhaps the IEnemy<T> could work! ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage a generic `IEnemy` interface to use it with custom data (like `EvilSkeletonData`, `BossEnemyData`, etc), instead of having just a generic `Init` method. And non-generic version to have any common data for any enemy (like health for example)

```cs
public interface IEnemy
{
    int Health { get; set; }
}

public interface IEnemy<in T> : IEnemy
{
    void Init(T enemyData);
}

public class EvilSkeletonData
{
}

public class EvilSkeleton : IEnemy<EvilSkeletonData>
{
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public void Init(EvilSkeletonData enemyData)
    {
    }
}
```

Non-generic `IEnemy` interface also allows you to correctly pass the instance to `AddEnemy` method in `EnemyManager` class, otherwise you'll face with some casting and generic variance issues. Example of the usage

```cs
var manager = new EnemyManager();

var skeleton = new EvilSkeleton();
skeleton.Init(new EvilSkeletonData());

manager.AddEnemy(skeleton);
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I was planning to initialise the enemy inside the manager AddEnemy method this works best and solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, I was talking about this in comments (if I understand you correctly):

```
public interface IEnemy
{
    void Init(object enemyData);
}

public interface IEnemy<T> : IEnemy
{
    void Init(T enemyData);
}

public class EvilSkeleton : IEnemy<EvilSkeletonData>
{
    public void Init(EvilSkeletonData enemyData)
    {
        // Logic here
    }

    void IEnemy.Init(object enemyData) => Init((EvilSkeletonData)enemyData);
}

public class EnemyManager
{
    public void AddEnemy(IEnemy enemy)
    {
        // Initialize enemy ...
        enemy.Init(new EvilSkeletonData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But there is one line I don't understand. Why do you neeed: void IEnemy.Init(object enemyData) ... ?

Comment: Because the `EnemyManager` still takes a parameter of `IEnemy`, so when you call `enemy.Init`, it calls `IEnemy.Init`, not `IEnemy<T>.Init`. Then you need that line to delegate the call to the right implementation.